# Savechanges for update statement is giving error in entity framework core 3.1

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I am getting `Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded` error for updating entity.

If I am adding a new entity it is working fine. I tried the solution mentioned in other posts to fix it(like checking primary key is there, adding [key] in entities, etc) and it didn't work for me.

**Note - I created my DB first and then scaffolded it. Also, commented part in my entity(adding key) is not working either**. Please help

Following is my code -

Entity -

```
public partial class Groups
{
    //[Key]
    //[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Logic -

```
public class SaveGroupHandler : BaseHandler, IRequestHandler<SaveGroupCommand, saveGroupResponse>
{
    public SaveGroupHandler(ZTT2020Context dbContextSql, IMediator mediator) : base(dbContextSql, mediator)
    {
    }
    public async Task<SaveGroupResponse> Handle(SaveGroupCommand request, cancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = new Groups
        {
            Id=request.GroupId,
            GroupName = request.GroupName,
            AccountId = request.AccountID,
            ModifiedBy = null,
            ModifiedDate = null,
            CreatedBy = null,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        if(request.GroupId==0)
        {
            _dbContextSql.Groups.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            _dbContextSql.Groups.Update(entity);
            _dbContextSql.Entry(entity).Property(s => s.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
        }
        await _dbContextSql.SaveChangesAsync();
        var resultentity = await _dbContextSql.Groups.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).SingleAsync();
        var response = resultentity.ToResponse();
        return response;
    }
}
```

table -

[image]

Comment: Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: @Uuuuuumm Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Comment: Is autodetectchanges set to false on change tracker? Can you show us your context.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad dbcontext is auto generated as i created db first and then scaffolded it. Which part of context you wanna see as it has lot of information.

Comment: context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled